# Grails + mysql Create table name and column name in Upper case

Tags: mysql, grails, grails-orm

Creating mysql table from Grails domain class does not generates table and column name in Uppercase letters. table names are created in lowercase . Even when doing reverse-engineer with table names in uppercase letters the domain class is generated in lowercase only. How to created table with table and column name in uppercase ?

Comment: Why is it a problem that the (reverse engineered) Grails class names are not in upper case? You should be using Java/Groovy class naming convention - class names should be camel case with first letter capitalized.

Comment: ok then why does it created a new table with lower case on stoping and restarting the server after doing reverse engineering ? . How to make use of uppercaser table name.

Comment: You probably have your `conf/DataSource.groovy` - `dbCreate` var set to "create" or "create-drop". Change it to "update". and start over with tables in upper case

Answer (score 3):

You can customize table names with a custom `NamingStrategy`. By default Grails uses an `ImprovedNamingStrategy` but you can use your as described in the docs: http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/GORM.html#customNamingStrategy

This subclass of `ImprovedNamingStrategy` will generate uppercase names:

```
package com.foo.bar

import org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy

class UppercaseNamingStrategy extends ImprovedNamingStrategy {

   private static final long serialVersionUID = 1

   String classToTableName(String className) {
      super.classToTableName(className).toUpperCase()
   }

   String collectionTableName(String ownerEntity, String ownerEntityTable, String associatedEntity, String associatedEntityTable, String propertyName) {
      super.collectionTableName(ownerEntity, ownerEntityTable, associatedEntity, associatedEntityTable, propertyName).toUpperCase()
   }

   String logicalCollectionTableName(String tableName, String ownerEntityTable, String associatedEntityTable, String propertyName) {
      super.logicalCollectionTableName(tableName, ownerEntityTable, associatedEntityTable, propertyName).toUpperCase()
   }

   String tableName(String tableName) {
      super.tableName(tableName).toUpperCase()
   }
}
```

Specify it in `DataSource.groovy` in the `hibernate` block:

```
hibernate {
   ...
   naming_strategy = com.foo.bar.UppercaseNamingStrategy
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Burt, You can add also the following code to change the generated column name in database to upper case by overriding the other methods

```
public String propertyToColumnName(String propertyName) {
    return super.propertyToColumnName(propertyName).toUpperCase();
}

public String columnName(String columnName) {
    return super.columnName(columnName).toUpperCase();
}

public String joinKeyColumnName(String joinedColumn, String joinedTable) {
    return super.joinKeyColumnName( joinedColumn, joinedTable ).toUpperCase();
}

public String foreignKeyColumnName(String propertyName, String propertyEntityName, String propertyTableName, String referencedColumnName) {
    return super.foreignKeyColumnName(propertyName, propertyEntityName, propertyTableName, referencedColumnName).toUpperCase();
}
public String logicalColumnName(String columnName, String propertyName) {
    return super.logicalColumnName(columnName, propertyName).toUpperCase();
}

public String logicalCollectionColumnName(String columnName, String propertyName, String referencedColumn) {
    return logicalCollectionColumnName(columnName, propertyName, referencedColumn).toUpperCase();
}
```